# Выводить к каждому индексу только два крупнейших значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Как сделать так, чтобы в каждом индексе выводились только первые два значения? Убрать их из выборки нельзя.

```
count=[1.39,0.77,0.08,2.26,0.4,0.5,0.11,0.8,1.6]
data = pd.DataFrame(count,index=[['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
data
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просьба подсказать, как это можно сделать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Можно сгруппировать по первому индексу и методом nlargest получить строки с максимальным значением. Результат имеет тип Series, чтобы сделать DataFrame добавьте в конце `.to_frame()` . Я не стал переименовывать колонки и индексы, если надо, напишите, сделаем.

Ваша картинка не соответствует коду, поэтому результат выглядит тоже иначе

```
data.reset_index(level=0).groupby('level_0')[0].nlargest(2)

level_0        
a       1  1.39
        2  0.77
b       4  2.26
        5  0.40
c       6  0.50
        7  0.11
d       9  1.60
        8  0.80
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод [GroupBy().head(N)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) чтобы выбрать N строк в каждой группе (в том порядке в котором они находятся в DF):

```
In [81]: data.groupby(level=0).head(2)
Out[81]:
        0
a 1  1.39
  2  0.77
b 4  2.26
  5  0.40
c 6  0.50
  7  0.11
d 8  0.80
  9  1.60
```

PS чтобы выбрать N строк с самыми большими эначениями в определенном столбце можно воспользоваться [SeriesGroupBy.nlargest()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html), как указано в ответе @splash58

Comment: В заголовке *два крупнейших значения*

Comment: Но в выходном примере не крупнейшие значения

Comment: да! и даже картинка не по тем данным :))